# Should the LaTeX tag stay?

Tags: discussion, tagging

Should we get rid of the "latex" tag? Only 7 questions have been tagged "latex", four of which have been closed and [the most recent of which](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28937/creating-latex-symbols) is heading that way. There is already a Stack Exchange site for TeX and LaTeX questions, and I do not feel it is appropriate to ask LaTeX-specific questions here as they aren't really questions about mathematics. I can't think of a true mathematics question which would fit better under the tag "latex" than under another tag describing what is being done *with* LaTeX. So can we have the tag deleted?

Comment: The linked to question has also been closed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

ok -- I deleted the tag, and deleted the closed questions with no answers in that tag.

Comment: How about unlocking the migration pathway so that questions can be closed as off-topic-belongs-on-TeX?

Comment: @isaac is this really common enough to appear on the dialog? Diamond mods can migrate to any site..

Answer (score 20):

And to follow up about the different sites, please **do** send your TeX/LaTeX questions over to us at http://tex.stackexchange.com; and then while you're over there, why not stay awhile and have a cup of TeA?  We're really a friendly lot.